# yarn start is not working to run the new react app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, yarn-lock.json

Error code is:

```
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-scripts start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:488
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in D:\1.aRE\testapptwo\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss\package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:416:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:669:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\1.aRE\testapptwo\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\lib\safe-parser.js:1:17) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
```

Node.js v17.0.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to run in the project `npm i -g react-scripts` and then `npm start` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If using VS Code you could navigate to your package.json file and click on the debug button there, just as seen in the screenshot attached below.

[image]

I hope this is helpful to someone out there.